# Concrete Patch Help

Tags: concrete

I have an area in my basement that we just removed tile from. After removal a large area of it is in need of repair. There are also a few other areas that have some minor holes that need filling.There is a drain in the middle of the area as well. I’d prefer not to demo and redo the concrete and I’m conflicted as to what type of repair I should do and which type of concrete to use. I plan to finish by painting over it with Granite Grip. [image]Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think I'd consider just filling it with epoxy resin.  Concrete won't work for that thin a patch.

Answer (score 0):

It looks deep enough to fill it with hand mixed concrete. You can get bags of ready mix concrete at your diy stores.  If you are going to paint it, the patch will not be visible.